# NextAuth redirects to localhost in AWSAmplify

Tags: aws-amplify, next-auth

My Nextjs website is hosted on AWS Amplify and is using NextAuth for authentication.
When i try to signin to my website, the callback redirect takes me to localhost instead of my domain.
I have verified the configuration and environment variables they all look good, the website works fine in my localhost.
What can be the reason for this issue.

Comment: Make sure that you add `NEXTAUTH_URL` as an `env` variable with your current app URL. Otherwise it is set to localhost by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the below updates in amplify.yml

```
build:
  commands:
     - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env
```

Also make sure :
Your NEXTAUTH_URL has the right protocol as per your hosted website.
Its pointing to the right domain i.e www..com or .com

Reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#access-env-vars

Comment: Have you managed to make Preview works?